# Kernel-based differentiation

Tags: probability, quadrature

Consider a $\mathcal{C}^1$ function $V:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ where $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$. If a random vector $X$ has a parametric density $p_\theta(\textbf{x})$ that's smooth in its parameters and uniformly supported on $\Omega$ we can use the score estimator for a stochastic derivative wrt $\theta\in\mathbb{R}^m$:

$$
\nabla \mathbb{E}\left[V(X)\right] = \mathbb{E}\left[V(X)\nabla \log p_\theta(X)\right]
$$

Consider now $p_\theta$ as the density for $X\sim N(f(\theta), \epsilon I)$. Then $\nabla \log p_\theta (X)= \epsilon^{-1}J_f(\theta)^\top(f(\theta)- X)$. This then makes it look like we can get a deterministic approximate derivative for $V$ without access to a gradient oracle for $V$, for small $\epsilon$:

$$
\nabla V(f(\theta))\approx\epsilon^{-1} J_f(\theta)^\top\int d\textbf{x}\;p_\theta(\textbf{x})V(\textbf{x})(f(\theta)-\textbf{x})
$$

By continuity of $\nabla V$ equality should hold in the limit. Since the integral above looks like a Gaussian convolution, perhaps this is some kind of generalization of the standard $m$-dimensional finite difference procedure for generating an approximation to $\nabla V\circ f$.

Does this have a name? If $V$ is, say, $L$-Lipschitz at $f(\theta)$, then would using a quadrature rule for the integral yield a sensible gradient approximation (sensible being as good or better than the $O(m\epsilon^2)$ 2-norm error of symmetric finite differences)?

**Edit**. Perhaps the integral approximation is distracting. Let's assume we can compute the exact value of the integral and ask the same question about its accuracy for a fixed $\epsilon$ (indeed, for a Monte Carlo approximation, we can make the the integral accurate with high probability by the weak LLN). Though any thoughts on the internal integral would be much-appreciated.

Comment: Am I missing something? The score method, a.k.a., Likelihood Ratio Method estimator is your gradient "oracle" of $\mathbb{E}\left[V(X)\right]$, and requires evaluation by simulation or otherwise.

Comment: @Mark It's an estimator of $\nabla \mathbb{E}[V(X)]$, correct. Under the assumption that we can do the integral I mention, the restricted version of my question is equivalent to asking "how close is $\nabla \mathbb{E}[V(X)]$ to $\nabla V(f(\theta))$" for $X\sim N(f(\theta), \epsilon I)$ when $V$ is $L$-Lipschitz at $f(\theta)$. Though, when you put it that way, perhaps there is an answer via concentration by subgaussian diameter...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting a partial answer in hopes of inspiring a full one. For simplicity take $f(x)=x$. Reparameterize to $\xi\sim N(0,I)$. We are then interested in the quality of this approximation:
$$
\nabla V(\theta)\approx \nabla \mathbb{E}V(\theta+\epsilon \xi)
$$
Now, add an extra assumption that $V$ is $\beta$-smooth. Then we have enough regularity to interchange differentiation with integration:
$$
\nabla \mathbb{E}V(\theta)+\epsilon\xi)= \mathbb{E}\nabla V(\theta+\epsilon \xi)
$$

Recall that we assume that we can estimate the above term without access to a gradient oracle for $V$ with the score estimator and Monte Carlo integation. Now, note that by smoothness:
$$
\|\nabla V(\theta+\epsilon \xi)-\nabla V\|\le \epsilon_1\beta\|\epsilon_2\xi\|
$$
We're going to need the split $\epsilon_1\epsilon_2=\epsilon$. Then for any $r>0$:

$$
\mathbb{E}\nabla V(\theta+\epsilon \xi)=\nabla V(\theta)(1+\varphi_1)(1-\mathbb{P}\{\|\xi\|> r/\epsilon_2\})+\boldsymbol \varphi_2
$$
Where we can characterize all our error terms. $\mathbb{P}\{\|\xi\|> r/\epsilon_2\}\le O(e^{-r/\epsilon_2})$ by a $\chi_n$ [tail bound](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4816/what-are-the-sharpest-known-tail-bounds-for-chi-k2-distributed-variables) for any $r$ as $\epsilon_2\rightarrow 0$. Next $\left|\varphi_1\right|=O(r\epsilon_1\beta)$. Finally with $\zeta=\|\xi\|\sim\chi_n$:
$$
\|\boldsymbol \varphi_2\|=\int_r^\infty d\zeta\, p(\zeta)\sup_{\|{\xi}\|=\zeta}\nabla V(\theta+\epsilon \xi)\le \|\nabla V(\theta)\|\int_r^\infty d\zeta\, p(\zeta)(1+\beta \epsilon \zeta)
$$
Re-using the same $\chi_n$ tail bound we get $\|{\boldsymbol\varphi_2}\|=O(e^{-r})$.

There is some tension because increasing $r$ reduces $\boldsymbol \varphi_2$ error at the cost of $\varphi_1$ error, but the epsilon-splitting trick with should save us. E.g., to get $\ell_2$ gradient error below $O(\alpha)$ choose $r = \Theta(-\log\alpha)$ and $\epsilon_1=\Theta(\alpha/(-\log\alpha))$ and finally $\epsilon_2=\Theta(1)$.

This is probably very loose: the analysis was lazy and I dropped a lot of lower order terms. Moreover, I didn't optimize the bounds. But at the very least it seems that we can get $O(\epsilon (-\log \epsilon))$ (relative!) accuracy. This is worse than symmetric finite differences, but we didn't use second order information here. Integrating a first-order Taylor series of $\nabla V$ about $\theta$ would probably make the error absolute rather than relative and explicitly depend on $\beta$.